# SQLException in Rails when using relationships with a foreign_key in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationship, foreign-key-relationship

```
class User 
   has_many :disputes
end

class Dispute
    belongs_to :claimant, class_name: 'User', :foreign_key => :claimant_id
    belongs_to :indicted, class_name: 'User', :foreign_key => :indicted_id
end
```

@dispute.claimant.name and @dispute.indicted.name work fine.
But when I try

```
@user.disputes.where (claimant_id == @user.id)
@user.disputes.where (indicted_id == @user.id)
```

I receive an error: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: disputes.user_id: SELECT 1 AS one FROM "disputes" WHERE "disputes"."user_id" = ? LIMIT 1
What's wrong and how to fix it?
Thanks for help

Comment: have you tried this `@user.disputes.where("claimant_id = ?", @user.id)`

Comment: same error. i think the problem with :user_id, 
in my schema file
  `create_table "disputes", force: true do |t|`
    `t.integer  "post_id"`
    `t.string   "reason"`
    `t.datetime "created_at"`
    `t.datetime "updated_at"`
    `t.integer  "s_dispute_category_id"`
    `t.integer  "w_dispute_category_id"`
    `t.integer  "claimant_id"`
    `t.integer  "indicted_id"`
  `end`
I don't see in my table :user_id, so when I try to use relationship like @user.disputes ActiveRecord see for :user_id in disputes (but I have :indicted_id and :claimant_id instead :user_id). Wrong design?

Comment: I have posted the answer please check

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you use invalid syntax in `where`:

```
@user.disputes.where(claimant_id: @user.id)
@user.disputes.where(indicted_id: @user.id)
```

You are passing boolean value but should pass Hash with conditions for SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

I think changing the Association will resolve your problem.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :claimant_disputes, class_name: 'Dispute', foreign_key: "claimant_id"
  has_many :indicted_disputes, class_name: 'Dispute', foreign_key: "indicted_id"
end

class Dispute < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Now in console try like this.

```
2.1.0 :019 > u = User.first
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
 => #<User id: 1, name: "a", created_at: "2015-05-28 10:48:05", updated_at: "2015-05-28 10:48:05"> 
2.1.0 :020 > u.claimant_disputes
  Dispute Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `disputes`.* FROM `disputes` WHERE `disputes`.`claimant_id` = 1
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Dispute id: 1, name: "test", claimant_id: 1, indicted_id: nil, created_at: "2015-05-28 10:48:47", updated_at: "2015-05-28 10:48:47">]>

2.1.0 :025 > u = User.last
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  ORDER BY `users`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<User id: 2, name: "b", created_at: "2015-05-28 10:48:08", updated_at: "2015-05-28 10:48:08"> 
2.1.0 :026 > u.indicted_disputes
  Dispute Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `disputes`.* FROM `disputes` WHERE `disputes`.`indicted_id` = 2
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Dispute id: 2, name: "test1", claimant_id: nil, indicted_id: 2, created_at: "2015-05-28 10:48:54", updated_at: "2015-05-28 10:58:59">]>
```